# Visual Studio not loading properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi I have Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. Recently when i started it, it came up with an error message saying

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.SolutionNavigatroPacage,
>   SolutionNavigator, Version 10.0.0
>   package did not load correctly.

I continued and the VS opened fine, i opened my project and tried to build. It shows a message saying,

```
No valid exports were found that match the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == "Mef_MSDN_Article.ILogger") AndAlso (exportDefini-tion.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Mef_MSDN_Article.ILogger".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))', invalid exports may have been rejected.
```

I tried repairing visual studio which did not help any solutions?

Comment: Sounds like a possible HKEY conflict. Is this the first Visual Studio you've installed on that system?

Comment: Did it ever work?  If so, did you try using Windows Restore to go back to before you had this problem?

Comment: i can't herform system restore.... we reinstalled vs but no help. i ve vs 2008 installed and it works fine...